# Mercado envíos API - dimensiones del envío con mas de un producto

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Tengo un Ecommerce integrado con mercado pago y mercado envios.

Al crear la preferencia de pago incluyo los datos requeridos para el envío. La documentación indica que

> tienes que indicar el modo junto con las dimensiones y peso de tus productos. En las dimensiones incluye el tamaño total del envío:
>
> El formato es: alto x ancho x largo (centímetros), peso (gramos)

Indicando la dimensión en un solo parámetro (dimensions):

```
{
...

"shipments": {
    "mode": "me2",
    "dimensions": "30x30x30,500"
}

...
```

Si tengo mas de un producto.. Qué valor debería ingresar en ese parámetro? Con el peso no hay problema, el tema esta en las dimensiones.

Tengo que estandarizar con mi cliente (el vendedor) qué tamaño de caja entregar a la hora del envío?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así, pon un array en las dimensiones, así separas todos los campos por cada producto:

```
{
...

"shipments": {
    "mode": "me2",
    "dimensions": ["30x30x30,500","50x30,100"]
}

...
```